# Longest Strings in List in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to return the longest string in list in a dataframe. The original data will look like:

```
items
['pants','hat']
['clothes']
['mouse']
```

My desired output is:

```
items               longest_str
['pants','hat']     ['pants']
['clothes']         ['clothes']
['mouse','xx']      ['mouse']
```

My code is :

```
def longest(i):
    return max(i,key=len)

for i in range(0:2):
    print(df['items'][i])
    print(longest(df['items'][i]))
```

but it does not print out what I want. My ultimate goal is to find the longest string in the whole dataframe. Please suggest any other optimal way to approach it

Answer (score 1):

Just call your `longest` function within [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
In [492]: df['longest_str'] = df['items'].apply(lambda x: [longest(x)])

In [493]: df
Out[493]: 
          items longest_str
0  [pants, hat]     [pants]
1     [clothes]   [clothes]
2       [mouse]     [mouse]
```

Comment: the error generate because the items column contains null value

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'items':[['pants', 'hat'],['clothes'],['mouse', 'xx']]})

df['longest_str'] = [[max(x, key=len)] for x in df['items']]

df
```

Output:

```
          items longest_str
0  [pants, hat]     [pants]
1     [clothes]   [clothes]
2   [mouse, xx]     [mouse]
```

To finish up your total question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'items':[['pants', 'hat'],['clothes'],['mouse', 'xx']]})

df['longest_str'] = [max(x, key=len) for x in df['items']]

max((x for x in df['longest_str']), key=len)
```

Output:

```
'clothes'
```

Getting really cute:

```
df['items'].explode().loc[lambda x: x.str.len().max() == x.str.len()].to_numpy()[0]
```

Output:

```
'clothes'
```

Comment: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. I dont know is it because of the null value?

Comment: Yes  it is the NaN values.   You could dropna or you can uae .str methods or use if conditions inside of loops to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Use apply, maybe is better without your function.

```
df['longest_str'] = df['items'].apply(lambda x: max(x, key=len))
```

Comment: it is said that TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable